# Cannot run any process command in Symfony

Tags: php, shell, symfony, symfony5

I'm trying to run a linux process in Symfony 5.1 as described here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

(...)

$command = 'echo hello';
$process = new Process([$command]);

$process->start();

foreach ($process as $type => $data) {
    if ($process::OUT === $type) {
        echo "\nRead from stdout: ".$data;
    } else { // $process::ERR === $type
        echo "\nRead from stderr: ".$data;
    }
}
```

No matter what my command line is, I get the following output:

```
Read from stderr: sh: 1: exec: echo hello: not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the docs you mentioned you can see example: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#usage

```
$process = new Process(['ls', '-lsa']);
```

Source code for Process constructor:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.1/src/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php#L132

First parameter is:

```
* @param array          $command The command to run and its arguments listed as separate entries
```

Try `$process = new Process(['echo', 'hello']);` not `$process = new Process(['echo hello']);`

Comment: Thank you, I thought the arguments listing was optional.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to simply use [`Process::fromShellCommandline`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#using-features-from-the-os-shell)

For example

```php
$process = Process::fromShellCommandline('echo hello');
```